# Writing to files from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I tried to run this code:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
import os
from datasets import load_dataset

dataset = load_dataset('oscar', 'unshuffled_deduplicated_ar', split='train[:25%]')

text_data = []
file_count = 0

for sample in tqdm(dataset['train']):
    sample = sample['text'].replace('\n', ' ')
    text_data.append(sample)
    if len(text_data) == 10_000:
        # once we git the 10K mark, save to file
        filename = f'/data/text/oscar_ar/text_{file_count}.txt'
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
        with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
            fp.write('\n'.join(text_data))
        text_data = []
        file_count += 1
# after saving in 10K chunks, we will have ~2082 leftover samples, we save those now too
with open(f'data/text/oscar_ar/text_{file_count}.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    fp.write('\n'.join(text_data))
```

and i get following PermissionError:

[Permission Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7MkT.png)

I've tried changing rights to this directory and running jupyter with sudo privilages but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your error says the path is`/date/...` your sample code says the path is `/Dane/...`. Make sure your path is spelled correctly.

Comment: You almost certainly don't have permission to write to `/date/` or `/Dane/` as a normal user. Try just `data/` with no leading slash as that will try to write a file relative to your script location rather than relative to the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening :

```py
with open(f'data/text/oscar_ar/text_{file_count}.txt')
```

But you are writing :

```py
filename = f'/Dane/text/oscar_ar/text_{file_count}.txt'
```

And you're screenshot says :

```py
filename = f'/date/text/oscar_ar/text_{file_count}.txt'
```

You have to make a choice between `data`, `/date` or `/Dane` :)

---

Also It seems you should remove the first `/` in `/data/text/oscar_ar/text_{file_count}.txt`.

Explanation: When you put a slash (`/`) at the begin of a path, that means to look from the root of the filesystem, the top level. If you don't put the slash, it will start looking from your current directory.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that :D, but I've made a choice and updated my post. It still doesn't work and gives the same error (with the same filename :) )

Comment: remove the the first `/` in `/data/text/oscar_ar/text_{file_count}.txt` Then it should work

Comment: It worked. Thank you :D

Comment: You're welcome :)